# What is the best way to check whether ASIFormDataRequest is still in progress or finished fetching data?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, asihttprequest

In my app, i am having a scenario where multiple webservices are getting clled at the same time. I want to know the best possible way to chek if a specific ASIFormDataRequest is still in progress or not.

Answer (score 7):

You can set tag to ASIHttpRequest like yourRequest.tag and use following delegate methods. If completed success fully than it will go in requestFinished and if something goes wrong than it will go in requestFailed.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the following code it may help you

```
        if (!networkQueue) 
        {
            networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];  
        }
        [networkQueue reset];
        [networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
        [networkQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
        [networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:TRUE];
        [networkQueue setDelegate:self];
        ASIHTTPRequest *requestqueue;
         requestqueue = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str_imageurl]] autorelease];
         [requestqueue setDownloadDestinationPath:[str_downloadpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str_imgname]];
       NSMutableDictionary *dictinfo=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
       [dictinfo setValue:str_settingvalue forKey:@"SettingValue"];
       [requestqueue setUserInfo:dictinfo];
       [networkQueue addOperation:requestqueue];
      [networkQueue go];
```

**ON DELEGATE METHODS**

```
    //queue responder....
   -(void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",[request userInfo]);
         if ([[[request userInfo]valueForKey:@"SettingValue"]isEqualToString:kAppSplashScreenDOWNLOADURL]) 
         {
           //FORM DATA REQEUST FOR PARTICULAR REQUEST HAS BEEN SUCCESS FULL
         }
     } 
    -(void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[request userInfo]);
         if ([[[request userInfo]valueForKey:@"SettingValue"]isEqualToString:kAppSplashScreenDOWNLOAD]) 
         {
           //FORM DATA REQEUST FOR PARTICULAR REQUEST HAS BEEN FAIL
         }

    }
```

Regards
Nikhil